# select top 5 max records in "High" column and 5 min records from "Low" Column in same query and from same table partitioned by stock name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, greatest-n-per-group

we have 6 months historic data and need to find out what is the top 2 max highs and top 2 min lows per each stock for all the stocks. Below is the sample data

```
Stock  High Low Date        prevclose ....
------------------------------------
ABB    100   75  29/12/2019   90
ABB     83   50  30/12/2019   87
ABB     73   45  30/12/2019   87
infy   1000  675  29/12/2019  900
infy    830  650  30/12/2019  810
infy    730  645  30/12/2019  788
```

I tried the following queries, but not getting the expected results.. I need results such as top 2 high rows and top 3 min low in one result set. I tried below query but no luck..

```
select * into SRTrend from  (
  --- Resistance
    select * from (Select top (5) with ties  'H' as 'Resistance', RowN=Row_Number() over(partition by name order by High desc),* from Historic
    order by Row_Number() over(partition by name order by High desc))B 
    Union all
    --Support
    select * from (Select top (5) with ties  'L' as 'Support', RowN=Row_Number() over(partition by name order by Low asc),* from Historic
    --where name='ABB'
    order by Row_Number() over(partition by name order by Low asc))C
    )D
```

PS: Hurdles which I faced is when I tried to export data to another table, getting very messed up results instead of getting top 2 max(highs) and top3 min(lows), I am getting single rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `rank()` as follows:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        rank() over(partition by stock order by high desc) rn_high,
        rank() over(partition by stock order by low asc) rn_low
    from mytable t
) t
where rn_high <= 2 or rn_low <= 3
```

The inner query ranks records twice, by descending `high` and ascending `low` within groups of `stock`s. Then the outer query filters on top 2 and bottom 3 per stock (ties included).

Comment: Thanks, @GMB, It worked, just wondering is there any other alternative we can with subqueries.

Comment: One last question,  we are getting the output for the last 180 days, also in the same query for same issue, can I get the data for the last 30 days..ie.. 30 days max top 2 highs and min 3 lows. @GMB

Comment: @Kiran: I am unsure what you exactly mean... How do you define the top and bottoms over several periods? I would recommend asking a *new question* for that, with sample data, expected results, and explanation of the purpose.

Comment: Hi @GMB, just posted another one, follow up for this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59533542/selecting-top-5-max-highs-and-5-min-low-for-specific-period-say-past-180-and-30